# Show snapshot of articles in news list

Tags: python, html, django

I have this `news_list.html` template which lists all articles in their entirety. Is there any way I can show these articles as a snapshot of the entire article. Ideally I'd like to show a thumbnail sized image, the title and the 1st 50 characters and have the user click into the article to view it all. Can this be done and if so, how?

**Additional info**

this is my template(news_list.html):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}News{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
  {% for news in object_list %}
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ news.title }}</span> &middot;
        <span class="text-muted">by {{ news.author }} | {{ news.date }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        {% if news.thumb %}
          <p align="center"><img src="{{ news.thumb.url }}" /></p>
        {% endif %}
        <p>{{ news.body | linebreaks }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a href="{% url 'news_edit' news.pk %}">Edit</a>
          <a href="{% url 'news_delete' news.pk %}">Delete</a>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    thumb = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py

```
class NewsListView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news_list.html'

class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news_detail.html'
    login_url = 'login'


class NewsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = News
    fields = ('title', 'body', 'thumb')
    template_name = 'news_edit.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user


class NewsDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('news_list')
    login_url = 'login'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user


class NewsCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news_new.html'
    fields = ('title', 'body', 'thumb')
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Please, show some code, like your template, models and views.

Comment: Sorry @Stargazer. Was too quick to submit the question. I've added some relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `truncatewords` to the body element in my template:

```
{% block content %}
  {% for news in object_list %}
    <div class="card" style="width:300px">
       <div class="card-header">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">
          <a href="{% url 'news_detail' news.pk %}" style="color:black">{{ news.title }}</a>
        </span> &middot;
        <span class="text-muted">by {{ news.author }} | {{ news.date }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        {% if news.thumb %}
          <p align="center"><img src="{{ news.thumb.url }}" /></p>
        {% endif %}
        <p>{{ news.body | linebreaks | truncatewords:30 }}
          <a href="{% url 'news_detail' news.pk %}">Full story</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a href="{% url 'news_edit' news.pk %}">Edit</a>
          <a href="{% url 'news_delete' news.pk %}">Delete</a>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```